# How to stop running other tests in a module if a specific test fails in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a module with tests for pytest. There are many tests there, and the fist checks if there is a connectivity to a target. If this test fails, there is no reason to wait for all other tests in this particular module to timeout. I'd like to stop all tests in the module if this one specific test failed.

I found `pytest.exit()`, but it's too strong, it terminates the whole pytest run. I have other modules to work with, so I want to skip/fail quickly all other tests in only one (current) module.

Are there a way to do this?

Comment: You can invoke `pytest.skip()` explicitly, for example in a local autouse fixture: `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function") def myfixture(): if not condition: pytest.skip("condition not fulfilled")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@pytest.mark.skipif](https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/skipping.html) annotation instead of running another test first

```
def has_connection():
    return True


@pytest.mark.skipif(not has_connection(), reason='No connection')
def test_example(self):
    pass
```

If all the tests are under class you can add the annotation to the class, this will skip all the tests

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(not has_connection(), reason='No connection')
class TestExample:

    def test_example1(self):
        pass

    def test_example2(self):
        pass
```

Comment: It looks almost right, but `@skipif` is executed at collection time, and I need a test time skip. The connection happens to a server, which is provided through the `host` fixture of testinfra. (Sorry for not clarifying this in the original question).

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin If you don't mind the tests failing you can add an assertion in the beginning of the relevant tests `assert has_connection()`